# DBD::Oracle unable to connect due to OCIEnvNlsCreate error on MacOS 10.12.6

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, dbd

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle server in a Perl script.  The script works on other machines that are already configured.  I'm trying to set up my machine to allow me to do local development.

I have extracted `instantclient-basic-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip`, `instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip`, `instatnclient-sdk-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip`, and `instantclient-jdbc-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip` to `/usr/local/oracle_client`.  I have added that location to my `PATH`, `ORACLE_HOME`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables via both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` in an attempt to find a fix.  I have added the variables to the Perl script environment directly by setting them directly in the script:

```
$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} = '/usr/local/oracle_client';
$ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} = $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'};
$ENV{'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'} = $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'};
```

I have reinstalled DBD::Oracle multiple times with various environment configurations.  I can connect to the database using the `sqlplus` client installed to `/usr/local/oracle_client`.

Inside `/usr/local/oracle_client`, I have created symlinks for `bin` and `lib` pointing to the `/usr/local/oracle_client` dir (`bin -> .`).  The SDK also lives inside a subdirectory structure located at `/usr/local/oracle_client/sdk`, but all of the include files have been copied to the /usr/local/oracle_client folder.

What am I missing?